# Hive insert query : giving error of Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column.

Tags: hive

I want to know why my hive insert query giving this error
To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict, When I set it to 
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
It works for me.
What is the reason behind it ?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i really appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode
strict
In strict mode, the user must specify at least one static partition in case the user accidentally overwrites all partitions, in nonstrict mode all partitions are allowed to be dynamic.
refer : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML